# Как использовать sesearch из C++

Tags: c++, linux, selinux

Я хочу в своей программе использовать sesearch. `apropos selinux` говорит, что такая функция есть. Смотрю /usr/include/selinux - не нахожу там такой функции. Как (и можно ли вообще) из C++ использовать sesearch, подобно getfilecon и genfscon? Впрочем, даже этих двух функций я не нашёл в selinux/selinux.h...

Answer (score 0):

sesearch это же утилита, а не функция. Определенна тут https://github.com/SELinuxProject/setools/blob/master/sesearch

Comment: python( А мне из рук вон надо C++...

Comment: там если капнуть дальше идет cimport. но по сути загружается весь список из си и питоном фильтруется. попробуй найти dbus метод похожий